# Downloading and playing videos on phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, video

I'm trying to download and store videos to a local device (currently a Galaxy S5), and then play them using HTML5 video tags.

However, when I try to store them into the applications files directory, the files are not being saved (even through I'm getting a FileEntry object returned to the success callback.

My code is as follows:

```
                        fileurl = "http://timelivingapp.absolute-staging.co.uk/src/branches/cms/public/uploads/1418656353chrome.mp4";
                        filename = fileurl.split("/");
                        filename = filename[filename.length - 1];
                        dataTool.ticker.addRequest();
                        fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                        fileTransfer.download(fileurl,"cdvfile://localhost/files/" + filename,
                        function(fe){
                            alert("ok");
                            alert(fe.toURL());
                            console.log(fe);
                            dataTool.ticker.addResponse();
                        },
                        function(err){
                            alert("There was an error downloading "+err.source+" to "+err.target+"");
                        },true);
```

If I replace cdvfile://localhost/files with cdvfile://localhost/persistent then it does download them, but it's then stored directly in the /Android/ directory on the filesystem, not within the app itself which would be horrible (certainly considering there will be 500+ images and videos being downloaded!!)

Either way, I then try to draw a video tag, and the video doesn't load - using:

```
    document.getElementById("appBody").innerHTML = "<video  id='vidPanel' style='width:400px;height:400px;'><source src='cdvfile://localhost/persistent/1418656353chrome.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>";
```

Calling this, the video tag is drawn, but with a broken video image (the above was when I was testing with persistent, but even then when the file downloads (and I can see it in my file system), it still will not play.

Also tried using a 'native' URL, but that failed also:

```
  document.getElementById("appBody").innerHTML = "<video  id='vidPanel' style='width:400px;height:400px;'><source src='file:///storage/emulated/0/1418656353chrome.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>";
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the file target is incorrect.
Here you have Android File System documentation for FileTransfer. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

[Android File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRYLZ.png)

I had a similar problem, here you have my question with code to download and play videos: [Can't play local videos in IOS 9 with Phonegap app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263264/cant-play-local-videos-in-ios-9-with-phonegap-app)

**Write file:**

```
 var uri = encodeURI(file.url);
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        // var fileLocation = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory +
        //     '/Documents/' + file.folder + '/' + file.fileName;

        var fileLocation = cordova.file.dataDirectory + file.fileName;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        fileTransfer.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
        };

        fileTransfer.download(uri, fileLocation, function(result) {
            console.log("Fichero descargado: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
```

**Read:**

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

    var nativePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + nombreFichero + "." + extension;

    resolveLocalFileSystemURL(nativePath, function(entry) {
        //deferred.resolve(entry.nativeURL);
        console.log("Fichero native: " + entry.toNativeURL());
        console.log("Fichero fullPath: " + entry.fullPath);
        console.log("Fichero toUrl: " + entry.toURL());
        console.log("Fichero toInternalURL: " + entry.toInternalURL());

        deferred.resolve(entry.toURL());
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error al leer el fichero: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```