# Can't play local videos in IOS 9 with Phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, video

I made an IOS 9 app using Phonegap 6.2.0. I need to play videos with no connection, so I download it using cordova FileTransfer plugin:

```
        var uri = encodeURI(file.url);
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        // var fileLocation = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory +
        //     '/Documents/' + file.folder + '/' + file.fileName;

        var fileLocation = cordova.file.dataDirectory + file.fileName;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        fileTransfer.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
        };

        fileTransfer.download(uri, fileLocation, function(result) {
            console.log("Fichero descargado: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
```

I've tried different file locations to download it (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

Then, I return the file path using resolveLocalFileSystemURL:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

    var nativePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + nombreFichero + "." + extension;

    resolveLocalFileSystemURL(nativePath, function(entry) {
        //deferred.resolve(entry.nativeURL);
        console.log("Fichero native: " + entry.toNativeURL());
        console.log("Fichero fullPath: " + entry.fullPath);
        console.log("Fichero toUrl: " + entry.toURL());
        console.log("Fichero toInternalURL: " + entry.toInternalURL());

        deferred.resolve(entry.toURL());
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error al leer el fichero: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```

I've tried all file formats but none of them worked:

cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/97a7d50f-05d1-4642-96e9-b0b26ea41897.mp4

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6CD24D7A-7A39-4AFE-A43B-788FCDFCEB5A/Library/NoCloud/a88d38b8-85e8-4b9b-b57e-a8eb2731eb0d.mp4

http://localhost/library-nosync/97a7d50f-05d1-4642-96e9-b0b26ea41897.mp4 and using port 12344

Some formats do nothing, some show the button play strikethrough...

In all answers I had read they recommend to use .toNativeUrl() but it doesn't work for me...

I also tried cordova-plugin-streaming-media (I can't post more links), but it does not work (no play video, no errors...)

Any idea?

Comment: Try using cordova.file.externalDataDirectory or cordova.file.externalRootDirectory instead of cordova.file.dataDirectory

Comment: I think externalDataDirectory  is only for Android

Comment: My bad. I overlooked the question. Check out this links and see if could get some help - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media

Comment: I don't think is because of file directory or the way to open file, I have the same code for images and it works. Anyway, I will see.

Comment: Then look at the second link related to cordova media which is of more relevance to you

Comment: I think the second one is only for audio (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media).
If I try to play video with external URL it works. Only fails with downloaded videos.

Comment: Did you tried out this plugin - https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer This is the only video plugin i  have personally tried and it works as expected

Comment: I tried last weekend and it did not work... I think it's only for Android versions (https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer/issues/23) All I read says that IOS works fine with HTML5 video tag... but not for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

My code works good and play videos. The problem was in the URL to download the video, it gets a string with the url and not the video (therefore download and open file method didin't throw error)

Summarizing, toUrl() works.

Thanks @Gandhi for your replies.

Comment: Glad you cracked in Danny happy coding